# How to have same height for TextView as for EditText?

Tags: android, size, textview, android-edittext

I have a view with 3 lines, in one of them with 2 TextViews, in the other 2 one TextView and one EditText. How can I have the same height for all those lines, and the size of the TextView which replaces an EditText in one line have the same size as the other EditTexts?

Regards,
Eddie

Example code here:
I would like to have the 2nd TextView in the first line to have the same size (of the view itself and of the text within it) as for the EditText in the following lines.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <TextView
            android:text="Datum:"
            android:layout_width="60dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <TextView
            android:text="Zweck:"
            android:layout_width="60dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <TextView
            android:text="Betrag:"
            android:layout_width="60dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your example code?

You can use distinct sizes by using android:layout_width="wrap_content" and /or android:width="300dp" (same for height). Also check margins and paddings.

If you need to be more dynamic, you might consider android:layout_weight i.e. for letting 2 buttons have equal width and fill the horizontal space of the parent view you would set:
`android:layout_width="wrap_content" android_layout:weight="0.5"`.

**Edit**: They seem to be all the same size (filling the space left by the description on the left). Do you want to increase the font size of the TextView?

You could also use an EditText in all three columns but set the first to android:editable="false".

Comment: I added the layout to the original question.

Comment: There are 2 "problems". First is that the text height is not the same. 2nd the EditText is also higher than the TextView, resulting in a greater height for the row compared to the row with only TextViews. An invisible EditText should solve the second problem if there is no easier solution but then there is still another text height, and if I adjust this, the complete height is probably also changed then (and then again different).

Comment: You can change all that by setting the height manually and specifying android:textSize on your TextViews. Naturally an EditText will be bigger as a normal TextView, as it just needs more space to display the graphics. You also might want to take a look at styles to simplify your xml layout if you are going to use the same height/etc for different objects: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: My first try was to find out the height of the views, but at that time (before they are displayed) getHeight() returns 0. I'll use an unvisible EditText now and take a look at the themes page. Thanks a lot for your help, Eddie

Comment: I just tested it - invisible EditText and set height for the one TextView to 18 (which is the default for EditText on my HTC). Looks perfect on my device, but might look bad on other devices with other resolutions. If there would be a way to find out the height programmatically before displaying the view this could be done indipendent of the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android:layout_height="match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

`android:editable="false"` is deprecated.

Use `android:inputType="none"` instead